# Jasmine test with httpBackend doesn't return expected result

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, httpbackend

I have a very simple unit test for my $resource-wrapping service.  I have httpBackend mocked and setup to return an array of seven items. When I run the test, it reports that 4 items have been returned, not 7:

function (a1, a2, a3, a4) { ... }

Expected 4 to be 7.

Below is my service and my spec

=== service ===

```
/* original 
angular.module('TeamSportApp')
.factory('LedgerService', function ($resource) {
    var Ledgers =  $resource("/rest/api", { id: '@id'},
        {
            allLedgers : { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            postTransaction : { method: 'POST'},
            removeTransaction : { method: 'DELETE'}
        });
    return Ledgers;
})*/

/* Fixed */
    .factory('LedgerService', function ($resource) {
    var Ledgers =  $resource("/rest/api/:id", { id: '@id' },
        {
            allLedgers : { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            postTransaction : { method: 'POST'},
            removeTransaction : { method: 'DELETE'}
        });
    return Ledgers;
})

})
```

=== spec ===

```
 var ledgerArray = [
 {id:1, name:"Master Ledger"},
 {id:2, name:"User1 Ledger"},
 {id:3, name:"User2 Ledger"},
 {id:4, name:"User3 Ledger"},
 {id:5, name:"User4 Ledger"},
 {id:6, name:"User5 Ledger"},
 {id:7, name:"User6 Ledger"}
 ];
 ddescribe('Ledger service test', function(){
 var ledgers, httpBackend;
 beforeEach(module('TeamSportApp','ngResource'));

 beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
     ledgers = $injector.get("LedgerService");
     httpBackend = $injector.get("$httpBackend");
 }));

 afterEach (function () {
     httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation ();
     httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest ();
 });

 /* ORIGINAL ERROR 
 it('gets a list of ledgers', function() {
     httpBackend.when('/rest/api').respond(ledgerArray);
     var result = ledgers.allLedgers;
     console.log(result);
     expect(result.length).toBe(4);
     //httpBackend.flush();
 });*/

 /* All fixed using angular1.2.14 per [this][1] */
     it('gets a list of ledgers', function() {
     httpBackend.expectGET('/rest/api').respond(ledgerArray);
     var result = ledgers.allLedgers();
     httpBackend.flush();
     expect(result.length).toBe(7);
 });

 it('gets a single ledger', function() {
     httpBackend.expectGET('/rest/api/2').respond(singleLedger);
     var result = ledgers.get({id:2});
     httpBackend.flush();
     console.log(result);
     expect(result.name).toBe(singleLedger.name);
 });
```

});

Comment: use `httpBackend.expectGET().respond()` instead of `.when()`... and `.flush()` before the expected result

Comment: Why is `httpBackend.flush();` commented and `expect(result.length).toBe(4);`. I guess it was `7` when you got the error.

Comment: I tried your recommendation; same error as before plus this:

{Error: Unsatisfied requests: GET /rest/api in /Users/phaggood/Desktop/Dropbox/Project/Current/Incubator/mobileapps/dreamfactory/teamsport/test/js/angular-mocks.js (line 1488)
}
Uncommenting the flush() gets "Error: No pending request to flush !"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**Service:**

```
.factory('LedgerService', function ($resource) {
    var Ledgers =  $resource("/rest/api/:id", { id: '@id'},
        {
            allLedgers : { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            postTransaction : { method: 'POST'},
            removeTransaction : { method: 'DELETE'}
        });
    return Ledgers;
});
```

**Test:**

```
it('gets a list of ledgers', function() {
    httpBackend.expect('/rest/api/').respond(ledgerArray);
    var result = ledgers.allLedgers();
    httpBackend.flush();
    expect(result.length).toBe(7);
});
```

Comment: Error: Unexpected request: GET /rest/api
 Expected /rest/api/ undefined

Comment: It only seems to work if I remove {id: 'id'} from the factory, tho now I lose the ability to use Ledgers for query and getting a single instance - Ledgers.allLedgers() and Ledgers.get(someId)

Comment: All tests now working, see fixes above - I had to modify Liu's answer slightly.